# Select an option default by giving a value to select

Tags: html

Hello is there anyway to have a value selected by giving in a value?

```
<select name="color">
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="white">white</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
</select>
```

For example if I want black to be selected I would set `selected = black`.  
Rather than using `<option value="black selected>black</option>`

Thank you for assistance, please let me know if there is any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not averse to using js and jquery:

```
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="white">white</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#color").val("black");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with multiple select options, you can use this:

```
$("#color").val(["black"]);
// for single select option
$("#color").val(["black","red","white"]);
// for multiple select options
```